# preg_replace inside of PHP file

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a file that i'm parsing And I'm trying to replace `$mail["email_from"] = "test@example.com";`  with `$mail["email_from"] = request("email");`,(meaning that I want to replace all the lines that has `$mail["email_from"]` at the begining an `;` at the end) and here's my preg_replace:

```
$email = "$mail[\"email_from\"] = request(\"email\")";
$newcontent = preg_replace("/\$mail[\"email_from\"](.+);/",$email,$content);
```

What's the error in my code? and how to fix it? Much appreciated

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/26XkxWZJ)

Comment: does that make sense?

Comment: "$mail" is interpreted because you're using double-quotes. Use simple quote instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using good quotes and escaping all chars you need, this works:

```php
$email = '$mail["email_from"] = "test@example.com";';
$replacement = '$mail["email_from"] = request("email");';
$newContent = preg_replace('/\\$mail\\[\\"email_from\\"\\](.+);/i', $replacement, $email); 
echo $newContent; //$mail["email_from"] = request("email");
```

Comment: Could you please check the demo !

Comment: And could you please try my answer? It works as expected. See it there: http://3v4l.org/uDC6E#v5425

Comment: I might be completely wrong in asking, but why would you wanna print that text?

Comment: @PrashantBalan I don't even know neither but maybe to store it in a PHP file and using it later I guess

Answer (score 1):

```
$email = "$mail[\"email_from\"] = request(\"email\")";
         ^---double-quoted string
          ^^^^^---array reference
```

You probably need

```
$email = "\$mail[\"email_from\"] = request(\"email\")";
          ^--escape the $
```

Comment: I tried that I think it got to do also with the regex ! here's a demo :http://codepad.org/26XkxWZJ

Comment: you're going overboard with regexes. this could be done MUCh easier with a simple str_replace() than with a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Use `^` and `$` to specify beginning and end of line. Special characters like `$`, `[`, and `]` need to be escaped.

```
<?php
$content = '$mail["email_from"] = "test@example.com";';
$email = '$mail["email_from"] = request("email");';
$newcontent = preg_replace('/^\$mail\["email_from"\] =.+;$/',$email,$content); 

echo $newcontent . "\n";
```

outputs:

```
$mail["email_from"] = request("email");
```